# finding formula for generating function for recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

> I need to solve the recurrence relation 
>   $$A_n=2A_{n-1}+A_{n-2}$$
>   with $A(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n t^n$ and initial conditions $A_0 = 1$ and $A_1=2$.

I am trying to find the generating function and keep getting the incorrect answer, any tips?

**Answer:** $A(t)=1/\left(1-2t-t^2\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your recurrence is valid for all $n \ge 2$ and hence we have
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{n=2}^\infty A_n x^n &= A(x) - A_1x - A_0 \\
\sum_{n=2}^\infty A_{n-1} x^n
 &= x \sum_{n=2}^\infty A_{n-1} x^{n-1}
  = x \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_m x^m
  = x(A(x) - A_0) \\
\sum_{n=2}^\infty A_{n-2} x^n
 &= x^2 \sum_{n=2}^\infty A_{n-2} x^{n-2} = x^2A(x)
\end{split}
$$
and substituting this into your recurrence,  you get
$$
A(x) - A_1 x - A_0 = 2x(A(x) - A_0) + x^2A(x)
$$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

This is a
totally non-original working out
of the general linear
recurrence.

If
$a_n
=\sum_{k=1}^m c_k a_{n-k}
$
for $n \ge m$,
find the generating function
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n
$
in terms of
$a_{0..m-1}$
and
$c_{1..m}$.

(This is undoubtedly a duplicate,
but I just wanted to work this out
from scratch.
The algebra and rearrangements of summations
is complicated enough
so that,
as usual,
I am hoping that
someone might have
a simpler derivation.)

Given the linear recurrence

$a_n
=\sum_{k=1}^m c_k a_{n-k}
$
for $n \ge m$.

Find the generating function
$A(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n
$
in terms of
$a_{0..m-1}$
and
$c_{1..m}$.

My answer is

$A(x)
=\dfrac{\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{k=1}^{r} c_{k} a_{r-k})}{1-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k}
$.

My derivation.

Let
$A_j(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{j} a_n x^n
$
for
$j = 0$ to $m-1$.

$\begin{array}\\
A(x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} a_n x^n+\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} a_n x^n\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}  x^n\sum_{k=1}^m c_k a_{n-k}\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^m c_k\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}  x^n  a_{n-k}\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}  x^{n-k}  a_{n-k}\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k\sum_{n=m-k}^{\infty}  x^{n}  a_{n}\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  x^{n}  a_{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{m-k-1}  x^{n}  a_{n})\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k(A(x)-A_{m-k-1}(x))\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^kA(x)-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^kA_{m-k-1}(x)\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
D(x)
&=A(x)(1-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k)\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^kA_{m-k-1}(x)\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} c_{m-k} x^{m-k}A_{k-1}(x)\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} c_{m-k} x^{m-k}\sum_{n=0}^{k-1} a_n x^n\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}\sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1} c_{m-k} x^{m-k} a_n x^n\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}\sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1} c_{m-k} a_n x^{n+m-k}\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}\sum_{r=n+m-m+1}^{n+m-n-1} c_{m-n-m+r} a_n x^{r}
\qquad r = n+m-k, k = n+m-r\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}\sum_{r=n+1}^{m-1} c_{r-n} a_n x^{r}\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}\sum_{n=0}^{r-1} c_{r-n} a_n x^{r}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1} a_r x^r-\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}x^r\sum_{n=0}^{r-1} c_{r-n} a_n\\
&=a_0+\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{n=0}^{r-1} c_{r-n} a_n)\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{n=0}^{r-1} c_{r-n} a_n)\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{n=1}^{r} c_{n} a_{r-n})\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{k=1}^{r} c_{k} a_{r-k})\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore

$A(x)
=\dfrac{\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{k=1}^{r} c_{k} a_{r-k})}{1-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k}
$.

In this case,
$m=2,
c_{1, 2}=2, 1,
a_{0, 1} = 1, 2
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
A(x)
&=\dfrac{\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{k=1}^{r} c_{k} a_{r-k})}{1-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k}\\
&=\dfrac{(a_0-\sum_{k=1}^{0} c_{k} a_{0-k})+x(a_1-\sum_{k=1}^{1} c_{k} a_{1-k})}{1-2x-x^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(1)+x(2- c_{1} a_{0})}{1-2x-x^2}\\
&=\dfrac{1+x(2- 2\cdot 2)}{1-2x-x^2}\\
&=\dfrac{1-2x}{1-2x-x^2}\\
\end{array}
$